# Why is the default of field "hour" in os.time 12?

Tags: time, lua

The table parameter of `os.time` has three mandatory fields `year`, `month` and `day`, and may have fields `hour` (default is `12`), `min` (default is `0`), `sec` (default is `0`), and `isdst` (default is `nil`).

The `hour` field seems a bit strange, why is it default to `12` instead of `0` like other fields?

I also note that it's documented in [Lua 5.2 manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.time) but not [Lua 5.1 manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.time), but a little test show that it's true in both versions.

```
print((os.time{year=2014, month=5, day=13}) - (os.time{year=2014, month=5, day=13, hour=0}))
```

Output: `43200` (12 * 60 * 60)

Comment: Noon is the default time of day.  Is this strange?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I guess the authors think the same as you, but to me, the more natural default is the beginning of the day, thus `0`.

Comment: Once you can start arrays with index 1, you are able to start a day from 12:00 )))  Lua is based on zerofobia )))

Answer (score 2):

Found the explanation by Roberto Ierusalimschy from [here](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-01/msg00166.html):

> It was intentional. It is even documented in PiL (pg. 202, 2nd edition) (although not in the manual). I never realized that 'date' has a different default. (Noon seems to be more "inside" a given date than midnight...)